# Why sharepoint.users can not see the form?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I need a hand. I'm using infopath to upload a form to sharepoint but when I upload it admin account can see the form but the user can not see the form

Comment: Is the form checked in?

Answer (score 0):

Check the securtity level of the form.

Steps
Click the File tab.

Click Form Options.

Click the Security and Trust.

Under Security Level, clear the Automatically determine security level (recommended) check box.

Click the security level that you want, then click OK.